# Derivative of $\sin^2 (\sqrt{t})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the derivative of $\sin^2 (\sqrt{t})$ which I believe have done but the answer seems to be more simplified and I don't know how to arrive to it. Here are my steps

$$\begin{align}
& \frac{d}{dt}(\sin \sqrt{t})^2 \\
& = 2(\sin \sqrt{t}) \cdot \frac{\cos \sqrt{t}}{2\sqrt{t}} \\
& = \frac{\sin \sqrt{t} \cdot \cos \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t}} 
\end{align}$$

The question is how does this simplify to $\frac{\sin 2\sqrt{t}}{2\sqrt{t}}$?

EDIT:

I forgot to add $2$ but I don't understand why top and bottom don't just cancel?

Comment: [$\sin 2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities). So this will simplify to what you say, divided by $2$.

Comment: @Julien but I don't have $2\sin\theta\cos\theta$? The $2$ on the top and $2$ on the bottom cancels out.

Comment: $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{2x}{2y}$. Now you have the $2$ you miss at the numerator to apply the formula. Or if prefer, use $\sin\theta\cos\theta=\frac{\sin 2\theta}{2}$ directly.

Comment: @RonGordon Sorry, I am a little confused. I plugged this into W|A and it has gives me the same simplified form that I arrived at.

Comment: In response to the edit: It'd be _sin_ to cancel them out. The expression is $\dfrac{\sin(2\sqrt t)}{2\sqrt t}$ rather than something else.

Comment: Now that you edited it, it looks OK.

Comment: @RonGordon Could you please explain why the $2$'s don't just cancel? Is this just convention that you simplify the top into its trig identity?

Comment: I am doing nothing special, and the equations above are now all correct.  You originally had it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $y=x$ in the formula $\sin \left(x+y\right)=\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y$ then 
$$
\sin(2x)= 2\cos(x)\sin(x).
$$
Use this formula whit $x=\sqrt{t}$ to give 
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin \sqrt{t} \cdot \cos \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t}}=
&
\frac{2\sin \sqrt{t} \cdot \cos \sqrt{t}}{2\sqrt{t}}
\\
=
&
\frac{\sin (2\sqrt{t}) }{2\sqrt{t}}
\end{align}

Comment: Well for derivatives it's not necessary but for anti derivatives this one is really neat

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sin \sqrt{t} \cdot \cos \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t}}=\frac{2\sin \sqrt{t} \cdot \cos \sqrt{t}}{2\sqrt{t}}=\frac{\sin (2\sqrt{t}) }{2\sqrt{t}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct and the target answer is missing a factor of $2$ in the denominator.  Here is confirmation from [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20sin%28sqrt%28t%29%29%5E2)